# check if two dates fall within schedule of two different dates

Tags: php

I have a schedule per day:

**8:30AM-5:30PM**

Now I have downtime:

**2017-03-01 10:00AM to 2017-03-02 1:00PM**

I want to compute the total downtime between this two dates that falls within the schedule provided above

Comment: I was able to compute the if both downtime falls within the same day since I am comparing by time and not date since schedule is only time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking this problem to separate part will make it easy to solve. You can sum up the downtime in the first day, last day and all the days in the middle.

a = Calculating the downtime on first day is min(0,[schedule end time] - [max(downtime start hour, schedule start time)]).

b = Last day is min(0,[min(downtime end hour, schedule end time ] - [schedule start time]).

c = All the day between are: ([downtime end day] - [downtime start day] -1) * ([schedule time in 1 day])

a + b + c = downtime in schedule

Comment: Hi Thanks @David Winder, I'll try to convert this logic to code and get back to if it was as success

Comment: Hi David tried coding it, question on letter C what is ([schedule time in 1 day])  ?

Comment: can you explain further letter C?

Comment: I meant [schedule end time] - [schedule start time]. In your case 9 hours

Comment: Hi @david letter C doesn't make sense, why do you subtract 1 to downtime end day and start day and multiply it by 9 hours?

Comment: Because you want to count the days between the first and the last. The subtraction is due to avoid count both of them. After having the number of day the system was full-time-down in you should multiple it by 9 -> number of hour that the system should have worked in those days.

Comment: Hi@david based from the example a=7.5 hours, b=4.5 hours, and c=18 hours, then a+c+b = 30, Maybe I should extract letter C?

Comment: in your specific case c=0 because the day are following -> the: ([downtime end day] - [downtime start day] equal 1, then subtract 1 and you get 0, then 0*9=0 => the final answer 7.5 + 4.5 + 0 = 12 which seem to be the correct answer

Comment: Came across with this problem what if I have a downtime: 2017-03-01 5:00AM to 2017-03-02 2:00AM, I'm getting a=9 hours + b=8.5 hours + c=0

Comment: You are right. I edit my answer - in a and b you should take minimum between them and 0 (they can't be negative - notice that c CAN be negative). Therefor, in you last case a=9, b=0 (min(0,-6.5), c=0

Comment: Hi, already made it working equating it to 0, however there are still a lot of scenarios I am still testing, one thing is,if there are holidays or non-woking dayslike saturday to sunday in between start and end downtime days It should not be included on the total downtime, should I open a new thread for this?

Comment: It is up to you. I gave you the general idea, non-working and holiday are location base and therefor should be calculate locally